# Not getting dynamically added input text's post value in jquery and laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

**Code of jquery:-**

```
$(".add-education").on('click', function () {
        var educationcontent = '<div class="row form-row education-cont">' +
            '<div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-11">' +
                '<div class="row form-row">' +
                    '<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">' +
                        '<div class="form-group">' +
                            '<label>Degree</label>' +
                            '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="degree1">' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">' +
                        '<div class="form-group">' +
                            '<label>College/Institute</label>' +
                            '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="clg1">' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">' +
                        '<div class="form-group">' +
                            '<label>Year of Completion</label>' +
                            '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="yoc1">' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-12 col-md-2 col-lg-1"><label class="d-md-block d-sm-none d-none">&nbsp;</label><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger trash"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a></div>' +
        '</div>';
        
        // edu++;

        $(".education-info").append(educationcontent);
        return false;
    });
```

**Here i am not getting output of dynamically added textbox's input in post method of form,**

[in the image the 2nd line or divison is added textbox dynamically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kbmxy.png)

**code of controller for laravel post method**

```
public function drprofilesettingpost(Request $request){
        dd($request->all());
    }
```

**The output gives only null value for the dynamically added textbox**

***The php blade template here***

```
@include('doctor.navbar')

<!-- Breadcrumb -->
<div class="breadcrumb-bar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-12">
                <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="page-breadcrumb">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="index-2.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Profile Settings</li>
                    </ol>
                </nav>
                <h2 class="breadcrumb-title">Profile Settings</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8 col-xl-9">
            
                <!-- Basic Information -->
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Basic Information</h4>
                        <div class="row form-row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="change-avatar">
                                        <div class="profile-img">
                                            <img src="{{url('/')}}/assets/img/doctors/doctor-thumb-02.jpg" alt="User Image">
                                        </div>
    <form method="post" action="{{url('/')}}/doctor/profilesetting">
                                            @csrf
                                        <div class="upload-img">
                                            <div class="change-photo-btn">
                                                <span><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload Photo</span>
                                                <input type="file" class="upload">
                                            </div>
                                            <small class="form-text text-muted">Allowed JPG, GIF or PNG. Max size of 2MB</small>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Username <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <label class="form-control">{{$userinfo->username;}}</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Email <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <label class="form-control">{{$userinfo->email;}}</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>First Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$userinfo->firstname;}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Last Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$userinfo->lastname;}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Phone Number</label><span class="text-danger">*</span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$userinfo->phoneno;}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Gender</label><span class="text-danger">*</span>
                                    <select class="form-control select">
                                        <option>Select</option>
                                        <option
                                        @if($userinfo->gender == 'M')
                                        selected='selected'
                                        @endif
                                        >Male</option>
                                        <option
                                        @if($userinfo->gender == 'F')
                                        selected='selected'
                                        @endif
                                        >Female</option>
                                        <option
                                        @if($userinfo->gender == 'O')
                                        selected='selected'
                                        @endif
                                        >Other</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group mb-0">
                                    <label>Date of Birth</label><span class="text-danger">*</span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$userinfo->dob}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /Basic Information -->
                
                <!-- About Me -->
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">About Me</h4>
                        <div class="form-group mb-0">
                            <label>Biography</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5">{{$userinfo->biography}}</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /About Me -->
                
                <!-- Clinic Info -->
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Clinic Info</h4>
                        <div class="row form-row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Clinic Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Clinic Address</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Clinic Images</label>
                                    {{-- <form action="#" class="dropzone"></form> --}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="upload-wrap">
                                    <div class="upload-images">
                                        <img src="{{url('/')}}/assets/img/features/feature-01.jpg" alt="Upload Image">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-icon btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="upload-images">
                                        <img src="{{url('/')}}/assets/img/features/feature-02.jpg" alt="Upload Image">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-icon btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /Clinic Info -->

                <!-- Contact Details -->
                <div class="card contact-card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Contact Details</h4>
                        <div class="row form-row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Address Line 1</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$userinfo->address1}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Address Line 2</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$userinfo->address2}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">City</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$userinfo->city}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">State / Province</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$userinfo->state}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Country</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$userinfo->country}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Postal Code</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$userinfo->pincode}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /Contact Details -->
                
                <!-- Pricing -->
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Pricing</h4>
                        
                        <div class="row form-row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>GENERAL CONSTANT PRICE</label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" value="{{$userinfo->generel_cons_price}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">VIDEO-CALL PRICE</label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" value="{{$userinfo->videocallprice}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">VOICE-CALL PRICE</label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" value="{{$userinfo->voicecallprice}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /Pricing -->
                
                <!-- Services and Specialization -->
                <div class="card services-card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Services and Specialization</h4>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Services</label>
                            {{-- <input type="text" data-role="tagsinput" class="input-tags form-control" placeholder="Enter Services" name="services" value="HI" id="services"> --}}
                            <input type="text" data-role="tagsinput" class="input-tags form-control" placeholder="Enter Services" name="services" value="{{$userinfo->services}}" id="services">
                            <small class="form-text text-muted">Note : Type & Press enter to add new services</small>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group mb-0">
                            <label>Specialization </label>
                            <input class="input-tags form-control" type="text" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="Enter Specialization" name="specialist" value="{{$userinfo->specialization}}" id="specialist">
                            <small class="form-text text-muted">Note : Type & Press  enter to add new specialization</small>
                        </div> 
                    </div>              
                </div>
                <!-- /Services and Specialization -->
             
                <!-- Education -->
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Education</h4>
                        <div class="education-info">
                            <div class="row form-row education-cont">
                                <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-11">
                                    <div class="row form-row">
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Degree</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="degree">
                                            </div> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>College/Institute</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="clg">
                                            </div> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Year of Completion</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="yoc">
                                            </div> 
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="add-more">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add-education"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /Education -->
            
                <!-- Experience -->
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Experience</h4>
                        <div class="experience-info">
                            <div class="row form-row experience-cont">
                                <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-11">
                                    <div class="row form-row">
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Hospital Name</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                            </div> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>From</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                            </div> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>To</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                            </div> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Designation</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                            </div> 
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="add-more">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add-experience"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /Experience -->
                
                <!-- Awards -->
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Awards</h4>
                        <div class="awards-info">
                            <div class="row form-row awards-cont">
                                <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Awards</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Year</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="add-more">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add-award"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /Awards -->
                
                <!-- Memberships -->
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Memberships</h4>
                        <div class="membership-info">
                            <div class="row form-row membership-cont">
                                <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-5">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Memberships</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="add-more">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add-membership"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /Memberships -->
                
                <!-- Registrations -->
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Registrations</h4>
                        <div class="registrations-info">
                            <div class="row form-row reg-cont">
                                <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Registrations</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Year</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="add-more">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add-reg"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /Registrations -->
                <div class="submit-section submit-btn-bottom">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-btn">Save Changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>      
<!-- /Page Content -->
</div>
<script src="{{url('/')}}/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{url('/')}}/assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{url('/')}}/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{url('/')}}/assets/plugins/theia-sticky-sidebar/ResizeSensor.js"></script>
<script src="{{url('/')}}/assets/plugins/theia-sticky-sidebar/theia-sticky-sidebar.js"></script>
<script src="{{url('/')}}/assets/plugins/select2/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{url('/')}}/assets/plugins/dropzone/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{url('/')}}/assets/plugins/bootstrap-tagsinput/js/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
<script src="{{url('/')}}/assets/js/profile-settings.js"></script>
<script src="{{url('/')}}/assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you send the data to the server?

Comment: Route::post('/doctor/profilesetting',[drprofileController::class,'drprofilesettingpost']);
with this route using and post method in form of blade template

Comment: no bro i have checked not same name.

Comment: ya bro i have checked i used form tag ending at the last and with browser inspect i have checked that adding element are in tag or not

Comment: bro in request response all post value are showing but the dynamically added field value not showing

Comment: the request is not containing the dynamically added input boxes data

Comment: Please post full code of your HTML page, and also the code that submits the form (if any) and any related code as well..

Comment: added bro plz check

Comment: ya bro now its working thank you but all the bootstrap is changed but i will work thank u

Comment: ajax request but now problem solved and alos css is solved now it is working , give answer in answer-box so i can give you upward and right sign to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form submit was not sending all the data because your form tags were not correctly placed in the HTML content, and therefore you were confusing the browser of which elements to include in the form submit.

Move your opening form tag before this line `<div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8 col-xl-9">`.